# Java Multithreading - main thread stopped

Tags: java, multithreading

I have Java app which reads data from IoT devices. For I have example smart thermometer:

```
public class Thermometer{

    private final String ip;

    public Thermometer(String ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }

    public void startReading () {
        Thread readThread = new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    //reading, writing data to DB
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //logging
                }
            }
        });
        readThread.start();
    }
}
```

In my main I add all my IoT devices and start their reading threads:

```
new Thermometer("192.168.1.100").startReading();
new Thermometer("192.168.1.101").startReading();
```

After a while (last time I've tryed it was about 12 hours) my main thread stops so all my threads stop too.
My log file (log4j2) has single line about this:

```
com.foo.Main - null
```

Probably complete stack trace was printed to sys.err. I will try to catch it and update post.

Why does it happen? How can I start all my threads so they will run forever?

UPD. Main class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thermometer("192.168.1.100").startReading();
        new Thermometer("192.168.1.101").startReading();
    }
}
```

UPD2. Starting script:

```
nohup java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=$PATH_TO_LOG4J2_XML -jar $PATH_TO_REEVE_JAR >> /home/buger/reeve/nohup.log 2>>&1 &
echo $! > $PATH_TO_PID
echo_and_log "Successfully started! PID = `cat $PATH_TO_PID`"
```

Comment: Post code executed in your main thread.

Comment: Show you main thread. But by default (unless you make them daemon threads), any running thread will keep the JVM alive, no matter what happens to the "main" thread.

Comment: @talex updated post

Comment: The only way to stop all threads including non-daemon threads at once is to call `System.exit()`

Comment: @AlexeyBugerya you main thread should stop almost immediately. Child tread shouldn't stop at all. Why do you think they stoped?

Comment: @talex I cannot figure it out. I im wondering there could be some JVM settings. Or may be even garbage collector truncates my thread because of innactivity. Update my app frequently but I dont remember any time I've seen uptime more then few days.

Comment: There no such settings and GC never kill treads. Some error happened. You have to check standard output for details.

Comment: @talex added my starting script to main post

Comment: You should add `2>&1` before `&` to redirect error stream too.

Comment: @talex Thanks. Added. Will wait for exception to happen

Comment: just asking, do the program able to maintain by a scheduler or something. If can, you can write a bash script to detect whether the program is running. Then use the scheduler to run the bash script every 5/10 minutes, etc.

Comment: @薛源少 unfortunately not. but definetly should be in future. currently delay between readings it defined by Thread.sleep

Comment: Not sure what might go wrong, but have you thought about using a scheduled executor instead?

Answer (score 1):

I think something happened to your reader threads. Maybe an <s>exception</s>  , achem, an [`Error`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) killed them. I suggest you to debug that.

Meanwhile, here is an example code that sort of proves my theory:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("--> thread 1");
            }
        });
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("--> thread 2");
            }
        });
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        System.out.println("--> main thread about to finish");
    }

}
```

This produces the following output:

```
--> main thread about to finish
--> thread 2
--> thread 1
--> thread 1
--> thread 2
...
```